# hide table cells output for missing values using Jquery/Handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates, handlebars.js

I have the table design in the following manner:

```
<tr>
  <th rowspan="6" scope="row">Payment History: <br><em>(Up to 25 months)</em></th>
  <td colspan="3">
    <table id="paymentHistory" cellspacing="1" summary="Payment History" class="table table-sm table-bordered" >
      <thead class="thead-default">
        <tr>
          <th style="white-space: nowrap;"></th>
          <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Jan</th>
          <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Feb</th>
          <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Mar</th>
          <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Apr</th>
          <th style="white-space: nowrap;">May</th>
          <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Jun</th>
          <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Jul</th>
          <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Aug</th>
          <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Sept</th>
          <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Oct</th>
          <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Nov</th>
          <th style="white-space: nowrap;">Dec</th>
        </tr>
        {{#each PaymentProfile}}
        <tr>
          <th rowspan="2">{{@key}}</th>
        </tr>
        <!--<tr>-->
        <!--{{#each this}}-->

        <!--<th style="white-space: nowrap;">{{months @key}}</th>-->
        <!--{{/each}}-->
        <!--</tr>-->
        <tr>
          {{#each this}}
          <td style="height: 42px;">{{hideEmptyData this}}</td>
          {{/each}}
        </tr>
        {{/each}}
      </thead>
    </table>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I have some cells which are empty for certain rows. The JSON from which I am rendering has some empty fields/elements, due to which they are not displaying on the table. I want to hide those cells which are empty.

Do I have to write a registerHelper or jquery function? How would I do that?

```
 $("#paymentHistory > tbody > tr").each(function() {
            console.log("inside table");
            $td=$(this).find('td');
            if($td.text() === ''){
                $(this).css("display", "none");
            }
            // $(this).parent().hide();

        });
```

I am trying above code. But i am not able to enter into the function itself. 
I am not able to print "inside table" in console. 
Can someone suggest me what i am doing wrong ?

So what I want to do is to hide the table cells which are empty. For example, in the year 2014, elements for all of the months are empty, so I don't want to display the row of 2014; and in 2015 only elements for JAN to AUG should be displayed because the others are empty.

JSON Data is as follows:

```
"PaymentProfile":{  
                     "2015":{  
                        "1":"9",
                        "2":"-",
                        "3":"-",
                        "4":"-",
                        "5":"-",
                        "6":"9",
                        "7":"9",
                        "8":"B",
                        "9":" ",
                        "10":" ",
                        "11":" ",
                        "12":" "
                     },
                     "2014":{  
                        "1":" ",
                        "2":" ",
                        "3":" ",
                        "4":" ",
                        "5":" ",
                        "6":" ",
                        "7":" ",
                        "8":" ",
                        "9":" ",
                        "10":" ",
                        "11":" ",
                        "12":" "
                     }
                  },
```

Can someone help me out?
[Output of the above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/226CA.png)

Comment: `{{#if td}} <td> ... </td> {{/if}}`

Comment: @awd thing is i don't want to display the whole 2014 row as all the months are empty.
so how can i do that ?

Comment: I think it would help if you would provide an example of your data.

Comment: @76484 u mean JSON Data ??

Comment: I would format the data _before_ passing it to the template. For example, removing the years for which there are no month values.

Comment: how can i do that @76484?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved the above problem using following code:
Hope it helps someone.

```
$('#paymentHistory tbody tr').each(function(){                       
                        var tr = $(this);                      
                        var tdNumber = tr.find('td').length;
                        var counter = 0;
                        tr.find('td').each(function () {                        
                            if ( $(this).text().trim() == '' ) counter++;                     
                        });                      
                        if ( counter == tdNumber ) tr.hide();
                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, do not add inline style: `height: 42px` on your table cell. `<td>` has no height by default, so if you put no content inside, it will have `height:0`. Now, the `<tr>` is the same - it does have `height: 0` by default and gets `height` of its children, which means that if there aren't any, it will not be visible due to the default `height` property.

Look at the example:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Row</th>
    <th>C1</th>
    <th>C2</th>
    <th>C3</th>
    <th>C4</th>
    <th>C5</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1st row</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2nd row</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4th row</td>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The *third row* is there in the HTML code, but it is not visible by default, as it's empty. So all you need to do is to remove the default inline styles to achieve this effect. If you want to add the `height: 42px` for the table cell, consider using  CSS (but not inline - use `<style>` tag in the `<head>` of your file or `<link>` it from an external `.css` stylesheet):

```
td:not(:empty) {
    height: 42px;
}
```

Ref: [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot), [`:empty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:empty)

Comment: this is not working. 
moreover my first priority is don't display the row of 2014 if it's totally empty.
how can i solve that ??

Comment: Notice the third row in my answer - it is totally empty & it is not visible - seems like exactly what you want. I don't think I understand what you need, as setting `td:empty { height: 42px; }` seems to be doing the opposite: it gives 42px height to the empty elements.

Comment: yes your code works when i remove the helper hideEmptyData. 
I want to remove the row of 2014 in which months don't have the data.
see my JSON data and my output Table